# Replacing Light kit of a ceiling fan, from regular bulb to a led light

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan, led

I have a 2013 Fanimation Zonix ceiling fan. I want to add light kit but the one they have for that model is HUGE. The inside black and white wiring  are getting hooked to a regular bulb.

The new generation kit has an led light, slim  cover, but it has 9 pin connector that will be hooked to light kit (*LED type*).

What can I do to convert/add to the black and white wiring, so that it will have 9 pin connector plug AND will match the lower W (18W) that the LED has.

Comment: Something to consider is that when they redesigned the light kit to have the 9-pin connector and LED bulbs, they may have also redesigned the mounting for the light kit itself. That means that it's _possible_ that the new light just won't mount to the older fan without some modification of one or the other by you. I'd strongly recommend checking with the manufacturer to see if it's even possible to do so before you spend money on the lights and start hacking into the wiring.

Comment: Your fan probably has provision to provide 120V AC, perhaps on a dimmer, to a light kit.  It's hard to imagine why a light kit would need a 9 pin connector but if it DOES, and unless it ONLY uses two of those pins for AC power and that's the whole story, I can't see how this will work.   At the risk of not answering your question my advice is this: Ceiling fans provide woefully dim light.  Get the big light kit and put overspec'd LED bulbs in it.  EG if it wants 3x60W bulbs, put 3x20W LEDs in it.  The light is amazing.  Shop around because some LEDs overheat and fail when in an enclosed dome.

Comment: Thank you  jay613 and FreeMan. I am awaiting manufacturer answer. I fear I will need to buy new one, Mine is so beautiful and new one is expensive. but I think you both are right.